# PHP if-else if working on local but not in live server

Tags: php

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"localhost")>=0)
  {
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$con)
     {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
  } 
else if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"www.mydomain.com")>=0)
    {
       $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'Eexam', 'exam');
       if (!$con)
       {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }
    }
```

This code is making a connection in localhost but doesn't working in my live server . I will appreciate you if have a solution.

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the mysql_ functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: have you checked if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` applies with any of your conditions?

Comment: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'Eexam', 'exam');` Is `localhost` a valid connection on your webserver?

Comment: Yes if I print then it is printing the domain name in live server.

Comment: Might the strpos function return 0 by any chance?

Comment: No if I only connect with "$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'baseer_Eexam', 'baseer');" .It's working.@ War10ck

Comment: What's wrong with using `if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "www.mydomain.com"){` instead of all this strpos malarky?

Comment: I don't under stand who vote it down? I think this is not a rubbish question. But who did that . Please do not close the way for beginner.Make mind soft for novice.If it will happen I will not be able to question again.

Comment: Another man vote it down but why I don't understand. I did not got my answer yet.

Comment: @Md.Ashikuzzaman Everything boils down to if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"www.mydomain.com")>=0) but we have no idea what $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is so how exactly can we help you? When someone asked what $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is currently you responded "Domain name , Please read the question attentively" which is quite rude to someone trying solve your problem as its really the only way to know what's wrong

Comment: Please $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"www.mydomain.com" I did not mean like what you think . I just tell it frankly and know they are like a boss of mine . So I have came here. But you redirect it in different mind , sorry .

Comment: Thanks every one for helping me . I have got solution. The problem was using  output before header in that mysql connection script page . Thanks to stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks Halfwar for instructing me @Halfwarr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess because the condition below is not met:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"www.mydomain.com")>=0)
```

Try to check the content of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Or you can switch to an if/else like:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') >== 0)
{
    //Development connexion here...
} else {
    //Production connexion here...
}
```

Comment: Yes it is being print. Also header in condition is not working in which page I include this code.

Comment: Can you report what is exactly in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']? Does a "Could not connect" is shown?

Comment: Yeah but please understand that you are not helping by not answering questions... If the www is not in the HTTP_HOST your condition is not met and you have your problem

Comment: No , when I print then the output is www.mydomain.com . But when i am adding the code for database connection or header in the condition that doesn't working.

Comment: So you see "Could not connect" message then?

Comment: even this condition is also not working.    if(isset($_POST['keepme_login']))
       { 
      echo "something";
               setcookie("email",$email,time()+36000);
               setcookie("password",$password,time()+36000);
                   header('Location:index.php');
     }
    else 
       {
      $verify=1;
      header('Location:verify.php');
    }

Comment: This code has nothing to do with your question and just confuse me (and that code won't work - can't change headers when content has been sent - unless you buffer your output which I doubt). Try to stay on topic if you want help :)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have got a solution in which page I used including the database connection page in same page I used header .But before header I used echo means an output function it is the faulty point. Is n't it , am also confused. I find this some where in stackoverflow. Thanks for helping me .

Comment: Also your testing procedure help me . thanks lot . i am leaving but accepting your answer.@AlexV

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"mydomain.com") != FALSE)
```